¿Como descargar un Archivo con PHP MVC Y PDO?
Buenas tardes compañeros, me encuentro en la situación de recuerrir a ustedes, para que me puedan ayudar que estoy realizando de manera erronea el cual no me esta permitiendo descargar los archivos subidos a mi BD, Le comparto la estructura de mi Base de datos. tengo un tabla que se llama firma con las siguientes columnas.

Esta es mi interfaz ya me permite, editar y eliminar registros, lo que no logro realizar, es que me permita descargar el archivo.

Mi problema esta en la acción descargar, no me permite descargar como mencione anteriormente descargar el archivo, estoy utilizando MVC con PDO he intentado de muchas formas pero no logro que me descargue el archivo, no me muestra ningun error en el navegado, mucho menos al intentar depurar mi codigo, Espero me puedan ayudar, les comparto el siguiente codigo:
Codigo firma.modelo.php


*===============================a==============
                   DESCARGAR ARCHIVO
    =============================================*/
    public static function descargarFirmaElectronica($idArchivo)
    {
        try {
            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT ruta_archivo FROM firma WHERE id = :id");

            $stmt->bindParam(":id", $idArchivo, PDO::PARAM_INT);

            $stmt->execute();

            $resultado = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


            return $resultado;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            error_log("Error al descargar la firma electrónica: " . $e->getMessage());

            return false;
        }
    }
}



Acontinuación les comparto mi codigo de la vista, estoy utilizando ventana modal para poder seleccionar un archivo y poder subirlo con su respectivo nombre, Aqui les comparto mi codigo


<!--=====================================
  MODAL EDITAR FIRMA ELECTRONICA
======================================-->

<div id="modalEditarFirma" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <!--=====================================
                  CABEZA DEL MODAL
        ======================================-->

        <div class="modal-header" style="background:#3c8dbc; color:white">

          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

          <h4 class="modal-title">Editar Firma-Electronica</h4>

        </div>

        <!--=====================================
                CUERPO DEL MODAL
        ======================================-->

        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="box-body">

            <!-- ENTRADA PARA EDITAR EL NOMBRE -->

            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">

                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>

                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="editarNombre" id="editarNombre" placeholder="Ingresar nombre" required>

                <input type="hidden" name="idNombre" id="idNombre" required>

              </div>

            </div>


            <!-- ENTRADA PARA SUBIR ARCHIVO COMPRIMIDO -->

            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="panel">Subir Archivos</div>

              <input type="file" class="archivo" name="editarArchivo" id="editarArchivo">

              <p class="help-block">Seleccione un archivo si desea reemplazarlo</p>

              <input type="hidden" name="idArchivo" id="idArchivo">

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

        <!--=====================================
                    PIE DEL MODAL
                ======================================-->

        <div class="modal-footer">

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Modificar Cambios</button>

        </div>

        <?php

        $crearFirma = new ControladorFirma();
        $crearFirma->ctrEditarFirma();

        ?>

      </form>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<?php

$borrarFirmaElectronica = new ControladorFirma();
$borrarFirmaElectronica->ctrBorrarFirmaElectronica();

?>



Estoy obteniendo las acciones de mis botones desde un archivo que nombre datatable.ajax.php, donde muestro la tabla con todos los registros obtenidos.nombre el boton btnDescargarFirma


foreach ($firma as $i => $firma) {
            // $botones ="<div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-warning btnEditarFirma'idNombre='".$firma[$i]["id"]."'data-toggle='modal'data-target='#modalEditarFirma'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button><button class='btn btn-danger btnElininarFirma' idNombre='".$firma[$i]["id"]."'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button></div>";
            $botones = "<div class='btn-group'>
                            <button class='btn btn-warning btnEditarFirma' idNombre='" . $firma["id"] . "' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalEditarFirma'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button>
                            <button class='btn btn-danger btnEliminarFirma' idNombre='" . $firma["id"] . "'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button>
                            <button class='btn btn-primary btnDescargarFirma' idNombre='" . $firma["id"] . "'><i class='fa fa-download'></i></button>
                        </div>";

            $datosJson[] = array(
                ($i + 1),
                $firma["nombre"],
                $firma["ruta_archivo"],
                $firma["fecha"],
                $botones
            );
        }



Por ultimo estoy manipulando las acciones de descargar el archivo con JS, muestro una ventana de alerta, si requiere descargar el archivo, en dado caso que no requiera descargarlo, que se cancel, les comparto mi codigo JS para que puedan visualizar y me puedan orientar que estoy realizando de manera erronea.


/*=============================================
          DESCARGAR FIRMA ELECTRONICA
=============================================*/

$(".tablaFirma tbody").on("click", "button.btnDescargarFirma", function () {
    var idArchivo = $(this).attr("idNombre");

    console.log("idArchivo", idArchivo);

    Swal.fire({
        title: "¿Desea Descargar este Archivo?",
        text: "¡Si no estás seguro de descargar este Archivo, puedes cancelar esta acción!",
        icon: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
        cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
        confirmButtonText: "Si, Descargar Archivo",
    }).then(function (result) {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            // Redireccionar a la ruta que maneja la descarga del archivo con el ID adecuado
            window.location.href = "index.php?ruta=firma&idArchivo=" + idArchivo;
        }
    });
});



Me olvidaba de algun importante compartirle mi archivo firma.controlador, que es practicamente la logica de donde obtiene y recibe la ubicación del archivo para poder descargar, pero no me muestra nada para poder descargar.


    public function descargarFirmaElectronica()
    {
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

            if (isset($_POST["idArchivo"])) {

                $idArchivo = $_POST["idArchivo"];

                $firma = ModeloFirma::descargarFirmaElectronica($idArchivo);

                if ($firma) {

                    $rutaArchivo = $firma['ruta_archivo'];

                    if (file_exists($rutaArchivo)) {

                        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');

                        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');

                        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($rutaArchivo) . '"');

                        header('Expires: 0');

                        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');

                        header('Pragma: public');

                        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($rutaArchivo));

                        readfile($rutaArchivo);

                        exit;

                    } else {

                        echo "El archivo no existe en la ruta especificada.";
                    }
                } else {

                    echo "No se encontró la información de la firma.";
                }
            } else {

                echo "No se proporcionó un ID de archivo válido.";
            }
        }

    }



Espero me puedan ayudar y arientar que estoy haciendo de manera erronea, quizas sea algo que estoy olvidando pero realmente ya me frustre y no encuentro la solucón espero me puedan orientar y ayudar para poder descargar los archivos, espero su apoyo. De antemano muchas gracias por ver mi pregunta.

Descargar cual archivo ???

agregas mucho codigo y mucha informacion y no logras explicar lo mas importante, 1 donde esta el archivo, 2 que has intentado para debuggear el codigo, 3 si no hay error que es lo que resuelve la peticion???

Estoy intententando descargar el archivo que subo en mi venta modal por ejemplo en mi interfaz subi una captura de pantalla, quiero que a precionar el boton de descargar, me descargue ese mismo archivo que subi.

y estas seguro de que llega a dentro de if (file_exists($rutaArchivo)) ??? ya verificaste hasta donde llega ???

si llega, ya lo verique.

y que sale en el header del request reponse en el tab de network?
